# Changing DNS for Subdomain

Tags: domain, vps, hosting, subdomain

I wish to point a subdomain to a different place to the main / root / origin domain - for example example.com should point to X.X.X.X while mail.example.com should point to Y.Y.Y.Y.

How do I go about doing this ?

Comment: That entirely depends on whether you host the authoritative DNS server yourself or whether you use some service. Assuming the more likely second option, you simply go to whichever control panel and add an entry for that subdomain. How exactly that's accomplished differs between services and you're better off checking their help docs and maybe asking their support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you registered your domain name, there would have been an option to set up the nameservers for it.  If you were not offered this, or just went with the defaults these nameservers will be controlled by the people you registered the domain name with.

You simply need to go into the control panel for the DNS, and make modifications.  Every subdomain can have its own record, and this is typically done through a simple web interface (but once changes are made they may take a while to propogate through the Internet - typically no more then 24 hours)

We can't provide more specific information unless you advise your domain name and/or registrar - but if you are struggling, you should get in contact with them as the first step.   You would want to ask them to Add/modify an "A" record for subdomain.yourdomain.name.

Comment: 3rd paragraph is what exactly i try last night. but i forgot to check your 1st paragraph seems y.y.y.y is hosting (limited config) not VPS like x.x.x.x (unlimited config)

Comment: i forgot. thanks for your editing my question. i appreciate that